# With Doxygen, how to generate a page that contains subpage links to all the .dox files in my project?

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I have a \mainpage that contains only the main page links.
However, I'd like to have a page in the final output documentation that contains all the page links to the .dox files.

I know this can be done using external scripts to parse the .dox files and aggregate all the page variable names. But is there a configuration field that does this for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use xrefitem + aliases to do something that might accomplish what you're looking for.

If you are not familiar with xrefitem and the lists you can create with it, then here is a reference: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdxrefitem

So, if you were to add the following line to your Doxyfile

```
ALIASES += page_list{3} =  "\xrefitem page_list \"\" \"List of Secondary Pages\" \3 \page \1 \2 "
```

You could then replace every place you use the \page command with

```
\page_list{page_name, Page Title, Some brief description}
```

Now on the top of every page you will see a : (which hyperlinks to the page list) and the brief description. You can change the {3} to {2} and drop the \2 in the command and you will no longer see that brief description on the top of each page, but you will no longer get a brief description in your list either.

I don't know how to suppress displaying the :. According to the documentation on \xrefitem

```
In case parameter "(heading)" is the empty string no heading is generated
```

But anyway, I hope this gets you a little closer.